# How can I safely deal with optional parameters

Tags: tcl

I am writing a proc to create a header in an output file.

Currently it needs to take an optional parameter, which is a possible comment for the header.

I have ended up coding this as a single optional parameter

```
proc dump_header { test description {comment = ""}}
```

but would like to know how I can achieve the same using args

```
proc dump_header { test description args }
```

It's quite easy to check for args being a single blank parameter ($args == ""), but doesn't cope well if passing multiple parameters - and I need the negative check anyway.

Comment: What do you want to do if your proc is called with more than 3 arguments: dump_header mytest mydesc {One comment} somethingelse ?  Treat somethingelse as another comment, process it some other way ?

Comment: It is wrong to compare $args to an empty string. args is a list, not a string.

Comment: well its not wrong per se, as it will create a string representation but this may be unecessary if you are going to the ntreat it as a list anyway

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your proc definition is incorrect (you'd get the error message `too many fields in argument specifier "comment = """`).  Should be:

```
proc dump_header { test description {comment ""}} {
    puts $comment
}
```

If you want to use `args`, you could examine the `llength` of it:

```
proc dump_header {test desc args} {
    switch -exact [llength $args] {
        0 {puts "no comment"}
        1 {puts "the comment is: $args"}
        default {
            puts "the comment is: [lindex $args 0]"
            puts "the other args are: [lrange $args 1 end]"
        }
    }
}
```

You might also want to pass name-value pairs in a list:

```
proc dump_header {test desc options} {
    # following will error if $options is an odd-length list
    array set opts $options

    if {[info exists opts(comment)]} {
        puts "the comment is: $opts(comment)"
    }
    puts "here are all the options given:"
    parray opts
}
dump_header "test" "description" {comment "a comment" arg1 foo arg2 bar}
```

Some prefer a combination of `args` and name-value pairs (a la Tk)

```
proc dump_header {test desc args} {
    # following will error if $args is an odd-length list
    array set opts $args
    if {[info exists opts(-comment)]} {
        puts "the comment is: $opts(-comment)"
    }
    parray opts
}
dump_header "test" "description" -comment "a comment" -arg1 foo -arg2 bar
```

Comment: Thanks.
For other cases I think I would prefer the name-value pairs... but in this case I guess your answer translates "to handle all cases you have to treat as an array". Which is fine.

Answer (score 5):

I use [tcllib](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcllib/)'s [cmdline](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/cmdline.html) library to do option parsing.

This is the example from cmdline documentation:

```
set options {
    {a          "set the atime only"}
    {m          "set the mtime only"}
    {c          "do not create non-existent files"}
    {r.arg  ""  "use time from ref_file"}
    {t.arg  -1  "use specified time"}
}
set usage ": MyCommandName \[options] filename ...\noptions:"
array set params [::cmdline::getoptions argv $options $usage]

if {  $params(a) } { set set_atime "true" }
set has_t [expr {$params(t) != -1}]
set has_r [expr {[string length $params(r)] > 0}]
if {$has_t && $has_r} {
    return -code error "Cannot specify both -r and -t"
} elseif {$has_t} {
    ...
}
```

So, in your case, you'd just use `args` in place of `argv` in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

It should be mentioned explicitly that `args` is a special word in Tcl that, when used at the end of the argument list, contains a list of all the remaining arguments. If no `args` are given, then no error is produced (unlike any other variable name, which would be considered a required argument).

I was looking for a way to have functionality similar to python's `kwargs` (optional key-value pair arguments), and something that works nicely is (similar to Glenn's last example):

```
proc my_proc {positional_required1 {positional_optional1 "a_string"} args} {
    # Two optional arguments can be given: "opt1" and "opt2"
    if {![string equal $args ""]} {
        # If one or more args is given, parse them or assign defaults.
        array set opts $args
        if {[info exists opts(opt1)]} { set opt1 $opts(opt1) } else { set opt1 0 } 
        if {[info exists opts(op2)]} { set opt2 $opts(opt2) } else { set opt2 -1 }
    } else {
        # If no args are given, assign default values. 
        set op1 0
        set op2 -1
    }   
    # DO STUFF HERE
}
```

And can be called like:

```
my_proc "positional_required1_argument" 
# OR
my_proc "positional_required1_argument" "a_string"
# OR
my_proc "positional_required1_argument" "a_string" opt1 7
# OR
my_proc "positional_required1_argument" "a_string" opt1 7 opt2 50
# etc.
```

A potential downside (as I've currently implemented it) is that if a user passes a non-approved key-value option, there is no error.